# Check whether a string contains valid set of parenthesis, string may contain smileys and frowny faces

Tags: algorithm

Recently I participated in Facebook hacker cup, there was a question named "Balanced smileys':

```
A message has balanced parentheses if it consists of one of the following:

- An empty string ""
- One or more of the following characters: 'a' to 'z', ' ' (a space) or ':' (a colon)
- An open parenthesis '(', followed by a message with balanced parentheses, followed by a close parenthesis ')'.
- A message with balanced parentheses followed by another message with balanced parentheses.
- A smiley face ":)" or a frowny face ":("
```

Write a program that determines if there is a way to interpret his message while leaving the parentheses balanced.

I did it using recursion and it was right but time complexity was high. I thought about memoization but still time complexity will O(n^2)/O(N^3). They posted solutions in which time comlexity was O(N)!

Solution is in python:

```
def isBalanced(message):

minOpen = 0

maxOpen = 0



for i in xrange(len(message)):

    if message[i] == '(':

        maxOpen += 1

        if i == 0 or message[i-1] != ':':

            minOpen += 1

    elif message[i] == ')':

        minOpen = max(0, minOpen-1)

        if i == 0 or message[i-1] != ':':

            maxOpen -= 1

            if maxOpen < 0:

                break



if maxOpen >= 0 and minOpen == 0:

    return "YES"

else:

    return "NO"
```

I know what code is doing but couldn't convince my self about its correctness or proof. How can we prove that it will work always?

Comment: When are smileys recognized as smileys and when as `:` followed by a parenthesis?

Comment: yes smiley :) and frowny face :(

Comment: I meant, is `(:)` a pair of parentheses that enclose `:` (balanced) or is it an opening parenthesis and a smiley face (unbalanced)?

Comment: I should be interpreted such that we get balanced parenthesis. e.g.:
(:) it is colon : inside a pair of parenthesis 
(:)) it is a smiley face in a pair of parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

u can understand it in this way:

each time u met a (, it can either be a left parenthesis, or a part of smile, if it is right after a colon. and for a string like :(), when u met (, the minimum number of valid left parenthesis is 0 and maximum number is 1. then u continue going through the string and met ). in this time, if the maximum number is 0, the entire string is not a valid string, otherwise it is valid.